# How do I force https and then match a RewriteRule that redirects from an old sub-directory to a new sub-directory?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Here is the code that I've written and an explanation below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.webringtheparty.com/$1 [R=301, NC]

RewriteBase /category/
RewriteRule ^our-rentals/concessions-tents-tables-chairs/generator-rental generators [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^our-rentals/bounce-slide-combos-rentals/(.*) combo_bounce_house_rentals [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^product-tag/moonwalk-combo combo_bounce_house_rentals [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^policies faq [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^about-us-moonwalk-rentals /  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us contact  [R=301,L]
```

I have an old domain name that I would like to redirect to my new domain and force https://www. The old domain name is

```
http(s)://webringtheparty.ourers.com/
```

and the new domain is

```
http(s)://(www.)webringtheparty.com/
```

I have setup

```
https://www.webringtheparty.com
```

as the main entry in my search console so I would like to force this format on all requests.

The problem with my code is that if I have written the URL as

```
http://webringtheparty.ourers.com
```

or

```
http://webringtheparty.com
```

and it redirects to the format that I want to force then no other RewriteRules are getting matched.

---

Here is the website I'm using to test the .htaccess rules:

https://htaccess.mwl.be/

Using the "Request URL" below and the .htaccess rules above I am expecting the "Expected Output URL" below, but it ends up as the "Actual Output URL" below:

Request Url: http://webringtheparty.ourers.com/about-us-moonwalk-rentals

Expected Output Url: https://www.webringtheparty.com/

Actual Output Url: https://www.webringtheparty.com/about-us-moonwalk-rentals

Comment: Is it the entire content of your .htaccess file? Is the document root the same for both domains? If not - are you 100% sure that this .htaccess file is placed in both the directories?

Comment: The document root is the same and I've only removed additional RewriteRules for redirecting similar directories. I've only tested it on the linked website though and haven't had a chance to try it on my live server.

Comment: You should definitely check it on your server (maybe on some development subdomain if you don't want to break anything on live environment) - these rules seem ok. This tool does not perform the redirect, so it shows you the output after the first iteration. If you then use: https://www.webringtheparty.com/about-us-moonwalk-rentals as the input, the output would be your expected URL.

Comment: @Jakub Krawczyk Thanks and the line after the RewriteCond has the flags NC, is that correct or should it be just N?

Comment: Try to look into the documentation first as it can usually provide answers to the most common questions. Then try to play with the htaccess rules yourself and then if you are stuck, ask the question here. I am sure that the SO community would like to help, but own experience is priceless and there is a chance of learning something new while exploring options. `NC` and `N` flags are two different things so it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've been going through the documentation and I feel I understand it for the most part, but the C option confuses me. I want it to redirect to https and I want it to also redirect old subdirectories to the matching ones on the new website we've developed.

Comment: But you don't use `C` flag there, it is `NC` which means that the rule is not case-sensitive. You'd have to have `[N,C]` in order to use `N` and `C` flag, but most likely it is not what you want. Your htaccess rules should work as desired, but test it first and if it doesn't work then ask the question.

Comment: I see, thank you for mentioning that. I got everything working and I appreciate the help!